# Aumentar valor de variable

Tags: java

Estoy trabajando en el siguiente codigo:

```
private void btnAñadirParticionActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                   
    DefaultTableModel tablaDatosParticiones=(DefaultTableModel) tablaParticiones.getModel(); 
    
    Object [] fila=new Object[2];
    int x = 0;
    
    
    fila[0]= x + 1;
    fila[1]=txtTamanio.getText();

     tablaDatosParticiones.addRow(fila); 

    tablaParticiones.setModel(tablaDatosParticiones); 
}
```

Me gustaria que al darle click al botón, el valor de x vaya aumentando

Como podría realizar esta acción?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declara tu variable `int x = 0;` fuera del `private void btnAñadirParticionActionPerformed`, por eso el valor de `x` no incrementa.

Comment: Muchas gracias, no me habia fijado en ese detalle

Comment: Realmente SI incrementa, incrementa en 1 cada vez que pulsa. El problema es que *se vuelve a declarar x = 0* cada vez también, no que no incremente :P